# CSV number conversion error

Tags: csv

I'm creating a CSV file and have to save numbers as 2 characters only such as "2" should save as "02".
How can I achieve this? 
I tried saving the fields as text only, but on saving the CSV file it changes the "02" format back to "2"

Comment: You'll have to explain more about what programming language you're using and what code you've got.  (If you're not using any, then this question is probably off-topic.)

Comment: I'm not using any code. I opened an excel file, typing in the values and saving it as CSV format.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.  You may have more luck at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the column is a format of "text", not "general".